# Android edittext check white space

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I check white space in edittext
if edittext is white space only return null
but I don't want to disable white space
cause some time user use "firstname lastname"
I try to check like feature change name in application Line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   EditText et_username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    if(et_username.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextUtils` class of android like this

```
String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
      //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextWatcher`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onTextChanged: empty");
            }  
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edtUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
String strEdtUsername= edtUsername.getText().toString().trim();

if(strEdtUsername.length() != 0){
    //Your code
}
```